# skip iteration on base of condition in handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

my input

> {
> "SheetID": "3605273345582980",
> "int_project_id": "4801220316292996",
> "123": "update row",
> "456": "duedeate",
> "789": "done",
> "101": "assine",
> "102": "done",
> "103": "thisis comment"
> }

expected output:-

> [{
> "cells": [{
> "columnId": "123",
> "value": "update row",
> "strict": false
> },
> {
> "columnId": "456",
> "value": "duedeate",
> "strict": false
> },
> {
> "columnId": "789",
> "value": "done",
> "strict": false
> },
> {
> "columnId": "101",
> "value": "assine",
> "strict": false
> },
> {
> "columnId": "102",
> "value": "done",
> "strict": false
> },
> {
> "columnId": "103",
> "value": "thisis comment",
> "strict": false
> }
> ]
> }]

code I tried

```
> [
    {
        "id": int_project_id,
        "cells": [ {{#each json_object}} {{#if @first}}{{else}} {
                "columnId": {{@key}},
                "value": "{{this}}",
                 "strict": false
            }{{#if @last}}{{else}},{{/if}} {{/if}} {{/each}}
        ]
    } ]
```

It worked I removed **sheetId** key and its value but now I want to remove **int_project_id** and its value while iteration
And I cannot write custom helpers
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why are you using Handlebars to do this? If your objective is to output JSON, why not using `JSON.stringify` instead? See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: This answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64419864/3397771