# How to pass an object to a .handlebars template and use it in a javascript code block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

server.js:

```
app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
      data['one'] = "first";
      data['two'] = "secound";
      res.render('home', { data });
});
```

home.handlebars:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var data = { {{{data}}} };
      console.log(data.one);
</script>
```

Browser Console Error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ] in computed property name`

How can I pass the object to use it in .handlebars template within a script code block?

Answer (score 3):

I think there a few things we need to review in order to arrive at a solution.

First, we must understand what the triple-mustache tag means in Handlebars. By default, Handlebars will [HTML-escape](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#html-escaping) its output. This is a best practice for preventing [Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/). This means that with input `{ data: "<p>Hello, World!</p>" }`, a Handlebars template `{{ data }}` will output:

```
&lt;p&gt;Hello, World!&lt;/p&gt;
```

There are some situations in which one does not want Handlebars to HTML-escape its output, and for this Handlebars offers the [triple-mustache tag](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#prevent-html-escaping-of-helper-return-values), which will output the unescaped HTML. For the same input and template above, the output would be:

```
<p>Hello, World!</p>
```

Second, we must understand what Handlebars does when given a JavaScript object as the expression between the double- (or triple-) curly braces to evaluate. Handlebars is essentially replacing the expression with the stringified evaluation of that expression - it's what you would get if you logged `data.toString()` in your console. For an object, the stringified value will be something like `[object Object]`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4750225/3397771) for a discussion.

For our problem, we must figure out how we can get Handlebars to render our entire `data` object and do so in a format that is valid JavaScript. Since Handlebars will render a String, we could pass it a stringified JSON object and use the triple-mustache to ensure that our quotes are not escaped.

Our route handler becomes:

```
res.render('home', { data: JSON.stringify(data) });
```

And our template becomes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {{{ data }}};
    console.log(data.one);
</script>
```

Comment: You still must html-escape the output, even if the rules inside a  `<script>` tag are a little different