# How to access the arrays of strings inside <script> which is inside handlebar page inline rendering from nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, handlebars.js

Here is the route `nodejs` code from where I am sending data by rendering this handlebar page to `script` code:

```
router.route('/profile/view/:id').get(function(req, res, next) {

  var element = "Buyers, Sellers, Investors";
  var  separatedStringArray = element.split(',');
            
              res.render('viewTask', 
              {
                 hiding:false,
                 separatedStringArray :separatedStringArray 
                });
})
```

And this is the handlebar page where inside I am having `script` code as follows:

```
<script>
var hide = {{hiding}};
if(hide)
{
$('.imag-close').show();
$('.commonText2').hide();
}
else {
  $('.imag-close').hide();
  $('.commonText2').show();
}

alert({{separatedStringArray}});

 $.each({{separatedStringArray}}, function(index, objValue) {
   alert(objValue);
 })

</script>
```

Although I am getting the `{{hiding}}` value inside script tag but I am unable to access the array elements inside the same `script` tag. I am not getting any `alerts` of array elements. How to access the array of elements here then? Any idea please help!!

Comment: It seems interpolation of array elements inside <script> cant be accessible easily.

Comment: Can't you set the string, instead of the array, in the script and then split it in the client?

Comment: Here, I have take the 3 strings as an example just to show the function. In actual the array of string varies. It can be of 3 array strings or 2 or 1 or maybe 4. So hence can't decide how many to split each time and then send to the script. I hope you got it what I am saying here. @EmielZuurbier

Comment: What is an Array to your template is not an Array once it is rendered into a JavaScript block. I would expect this code to output: `alert(Buyers,Sellers,Investors);`, and because you don't have a variable named "Buyers" (or "Sellers" or "Investors") you should get a ReferenceError.

Comment: @76484 I am not getting any alert. I just want to know how I can access that array into script of handlebar page. Tell me that.

Comment: It would help a lot if you would show how the array is being output to your script in the template. What does it look like?

Comment: @Biku7: I am trying to help you understand what your problem is. Using the developer console to identify the Error would be a good start. Next, you need to understand which JavaScript is executed on the server and which is executed on the client and that the two are not a single environment and they cannot just call each other's variables. Variants of your question have been asked before. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64407740/3397771