# How do you run scripts off of handlebar data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to parse data from a node.js/ express server which I wish to use on the client-side as a variable (although I understand this could most likely all be done server-side, I'm trying to learn about how handlebars handles data). At this stage I wish to have it as an object I can print so I can use it at a later stage. My current code is as follows:

**Handler for request**

```
exports.getList = (req,res) => {
  console.log("Request for list sent");
  var MyDataObject = {
      days: 75,
      people: 12
  };
  return res.status(200).render("home", {MyDataObject});
};
```

**Client-Side**

```
      <script>
        handleServerData = (ServerDataObject) => {
          console.log(ServerDataObject);
        };
      </script>
      {{#if MyDataObject}}
        <script>handleServerData({{MyDataObject}})</script>
      {{/if}}
```

When the page is requested through the shown handler this simply gives the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` Which I assume is from it setting `{{MyDataObject}}` to `[object Object]` inside the sources view however I don't know how to fix this although I assume it does it because of it running the script before the handlebars parse the data.

Any help fixing this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64419864/3397771

Comment: Thank you greatly.